# Eclipse C/C++ variable sharing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a Java Plugin project that I have added a C/C++ nature. How do I get these two languages to share variables between the different source files?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do. Perhaps you should give us an example of what you want.

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me after I posted the question that it might not be specific enough. So I want to be able to access the C project's build variables, specifically the "BuildArtifactFileBaseName" variable. I want the C project's build variable to be passed to the Java project that I'm making and I don't know how to go about doing that.